Adjunction symbol
What are the reasons for the adjuction symbol $F\dashv G$ for a pair of functors $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$? There is no explanation or motivation in the article of Kan where, afaik, adjunctions are introduced.

I always had the impression it was chosen more or less at random, as a symbol loaded with no prior meaning from algebra or topology (the "entails", or "is entailed by" is standard meaning in proof theory, pretty far from Kan's expertise). Then no one changed it. However, all this is 100% speculation and I'd be curious to see an answer.

Cf. this question
